# what is the best way to render many videos back to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-native

I have a nodejs server that renders media content back to my react native mobile device.

lets say we had 100 user who concurrently loading 100 videos on page load on my mobile app page. what would be the best solution to load that data and why? I'm kinda stuck between using data uri/base64 encoding all the video content vs simply getting the file from a endpoint i.e.

```
  <video src="http://domain/videos/" />.
```

I'm leaning towards loading the video files directly, as it would bypass base64 encoding the video data; thus saving mobile memory and improved performance.

Ideally another alternative(best solution) for me would of been to send a stream of video data back to the client via websocket connection; then each chunk of data would of been passed to the video element to render. the only issue is that i would of had to base64 encode the data.

Comment: May head over to https://medium.com/netflix-techblog